# jQuery nav bar with auth user name

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a nav bar to the top of all my pages (using twitter bootstrap)

the nav bar needs to contain the full name of the auth'd user.

I have a REST service /auth/rest/user/fullname for GET that will return "Jane Doe" in plain text.

I have multiple pages, so I'm looking for a solution where I can add a minimal amount of boilerplate code on each page.  something like this at the top of the page:

```
<div id="banner"></div>
```

and this at the bottom:

```
<script>
    addBanner();
</script>
```

any suggestions / ideas

I got my banner loading from a banner.html file using:

```
function addBanner() {
    $('body').css("padding-top", "50px");
    $("#banner").load("/banner.html");
    // how to replace the <span id="fullname">&nbsp;</span> with Jane Doe?
}
```

EDIT:  I need to load the HTML for the banner from the banner.html file.  That file has a span with ID=fullname which needs to be updated from ajax GET, and that entire "chunk" of html inserted into the div with id=banner.  I can't get both pieces to work.  I get the ajax to return my fullname and I can load from a static file, but how do I load, modify what I loaded via ajax and then insert into DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery's [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) methods. Although `text()` is minimally faster, I prefer to use `.html()` because if you decide to add any html with the text you are inserting it will not work as expected with `text()`.

```
$('#fullname').html('Jane Doe');
// OR
$('#fullname').text('Jane Doe');
```

Which will result in the same thing:

```
<span id="fullname">Jane Doe</span>
// which displays as
Jane Doe
```

However if you want to include html content such as `<h1>Jane Doe</h1>` the result will be:

```
<span id="fullname"><h1>Jane Doe</h1></span>
// but with html() it will display the text
Jane Doe
// whereas with text() it will display the text
<h1>Jane Doe</h1>
```

[Difference-between-jquery-text-and-html](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/02/difference-between-jquery-text-and-html.html) is a good blog post that explains this pretty well.

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K5Zd8/1/)

Concerning your edit, you should just load the banner and update the user information after the banner has been updated. Your add banner function would look like this:

```
function addBanner() {
    $('body').css("padding-top", "50px");
    $("#banner").load("/banner.html", function() {
        $('#fullname').html('Jane Doe');
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you should use .text() instead of .html()

Comment: @kannix Any particular reason why? You can use either one.

Comment: @kannix That is true, but it is so minimal that it does not make much difference. I also find it better to use .html() because many people forget that .text() should not be used when including html with what they are inserting.

Comment: what if you want to do `$("#fullname").text("<h1>Jane Doe</h1>");` -- It won't work. That is why it is always best to use `.html();`

Comment: see my edit.  I need to load, then edit what I loaded, then insert into DOM.  I can't get all those working together.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I went with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#banner").load("banner.html");
        $('body').css("padding-top", "50px");
        $.ajax({
            url : "/auth/rest/user/fullname",
            cache : false
        }).done(function(html) {
            $('#fullname').html(html);
        });
    });
</script>
```